# NodeJS and Mysql connection configuration ignored

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a weird behavior while I'm trying to query my MySQL database from a nodeJS API.
I define a connection pool to mysql on node using the following code

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: 'mydb.user', 
  database: process.env.DB_DB,
  password: process.env.DB_PWD,
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0,
  multipleStatements: true
}).promise()
```

Before that, I was using another user named `mydb.owner` defined in a `.env` file.

When I execute a query, I have the following error

```
Access denied for user 'mydb.owner'@'localhost' to database 'mydb'
```

That's not the user I've configured, that's the old one.

If I have a look on the Mysql connections, I can see that the user of the pool is correct:

```
show processlist;
```

Returns

```
Id   User         Host               db
6    root         localhost:37752    mydb
9    mydb.user    localhost:38102    mydb
```

It seems I haven't any environment variable defined from elsewhere:

```sh
echo $DB_USER
```

Returns nothing.

The user seems to have the necessary rights :

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mydb.user'@'localhost';
```

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mydb.user'@'localhost'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON `mydb`.* TO 'mydb.user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I don't understand why mysql2 returns me an error about my old user `mydb.owner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query was a stored procedure and was created by default with the tag

```
CREATE definer = 'mydb.owner'@'localhost' PROCEDURE ...
```

No matter which user execute the stored procedure, it was impersonated with the `mydb.owner` account.

To specify that the procedure must be executed under the current account, I added the following instructions:

```
CREATE definer = 'mydb.owner'@'localhost' PROCEDURE ...()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN ...
```